# Altering user password results in failed authentication

Tags: sql, passwords, hana, alter

I changed my user's password in SAP Hana using following statement.

```
ALTER USER <my-username> password "<my-new-password>";
```

But, now I'm not able to login to the DB using `<my-new-password>`? Is there anything I'm missing here?

EDIT #1: I'm getting `[10]: authentication failed` error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the user is locked because you tried to many times.

You can unlock the user using:

```
ALTER user <username> ACTIVATE USER NOW;
```

Comment: That is what exactly happened